# Visibility for twinx grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

When creating overlaid bar charts with two different height scales using `Axes.twinx()`, I cannot set visible the vertical grid lines of the 'twin' axis set. The horizontal lines work fine though. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Below is some example code that illustrates what I want to do and what I cannot do. As seen, the vertical grid lines are hidden by the red bars of `ax2`, whereas I want the grid lines to be visible through all bars.

```py
# Create figure and figure layout
ax1 = plt.subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Example data
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
h1 = [55, 63, 70, 84, 73, 93]
h2 = [4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 3]

# Plot bars
h1_bars = ax1.bar(x, h1, width=0.6, color='darkblue')
h2_bars = ax2.bar(x, h2, width=0.6, color='darkred')

# Set y limits and grid visibility
for ax, ylim in zip([ax1, ax2], [100, 10]):
    ax.set_ylim(0, ylim)
    ax.grid(True)
```

[image]

The error comes about because the vertical grid lines of `ax2` are not set visible. This can be tested by setting `ax1.grid(False)`, in which case there are only horizontal grid lines.

[image]

I have tried all combinations of `ax1.xaxis.grid(True)`, `ax1.yaxis.grid(True)`, `ax2.xaxis.grid(True)` and `ax2.yaxis.grid(True)` without any luck. Any help on this matter deeply appreciated!

Comment: Ok, obviously one workaround is to scale the `h2`-data with the `y`-axii ratio (10 in this case) and then plot `h2` in `ax1` like this: `h2_bars = ax1.bar(x, [10*h for h in h2], width=0.6, color='darkred')`.

Comment: Usually the grid lines are below patches. But you can set `ax.set_axisbelow(False)` to have them appear in front.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I actually already tried that. It does not work because there are no vertical grid lines in `ax2` to begin with, so they cannot be brought to the front.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think I misunderstood the problem. Indeed, `ax2` does not have any grid lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may revert the role of ax1 and ax2, such that the blue bars are on ax2 and the red ones on ax1. Then you need to put the twin axes in the background and tick the respective y axes on the other side of the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create figure and figure layout
ax1 = plt.subplot()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Example data
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
h1 = [55, 63, 70, 84, 73, 93]
h2 = [4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 3]

# Plot bars
h1_bars = ax2.bar(x, h1, width=0.6, color='darkblue')
h2_bars = ax1.bar(x, h2, width=0.6, color='darkred')

# Set y limits and grid visibility
for ax, ylim in zip([ax1, ax2], [10, 100]):
    ax.set_ylim(0, ylim)
    ax.grid(True)


ax1.set_zorder(1)
ax1.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax2.set_zorder(0)

ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is God! I tried so many ways but missed the `set_alpha`. +1 again

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for this workaround. It’s great, and I was also delighted to learn about set_alpha. It doesn’t answer my original question on how to make visible the grid lines of ax2, but I’ll accept it anyhow since it gets the job done.

Comment: The point is, `ax2` does not have any vertical gridlines, because it is a twin axes. Meaning, it shares the grid and ticks with `ax1` for the direction of the twinning.